# Can not retrieve data correctly from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my second version me trying to retrieve code from Firebase and do stuff with it. This is how I done it the second way:

```
    channelRef?.observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
        let update = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        var readyToGoValue: Bool?
        var userID: String?
        var amountOfPlayers: Int?
        var changedCreator: String?
        if let updatedReadyToGo = update["readyToGo"] as! Bool!{
            if updatedReadyToGo == true
            {
                readyToGoValue = true
            }
            else
            {
                readyToGoValue = false
            }
        }
        if let updateduserID = update["userID"] as! String!{
            userID = updateduserID
        }
        if let updatedAmountOfPlayers = update["currentPlayers"] as! Int!{
            amountOfPlayers = updatedAmountOfPlayers
        }
        if let updateduserID = update["userID"] as! String!{
            userID = updateduserID
        }
        if let updatedCreator = update["creator"] as! String!{
            changedCreator = updatedCreator
        }

        let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

        if changedCreator != nil
        {
            print("changed creator")
            self.creator = changedCreator!
        }
```

This crashed with an error code:

Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x10a77f4a0) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10a780288). at the line " update". This was my first attempt:

```
    channelRef?.observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let readyToGoValue = value?["readyToGo"] as? Bool ?? false
        let userID = value?["userID"] as? String ?? ""
        var amountOfPlayers = value?["currentPlayers"] as? Int ?? 0
        let changedCreator = value?["creator"] as? String ?? ""
        print(snapshot)
        let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        print(changedCreator)
        print(amountOfPlayers)
        if changedCreator != ""
        {
            print("changed creator")
            self.creator = changedCreator
        }
```

This doesn't work swell. When changing the creator (just a string) in Firebase, I get this as a print when adding print(snapshot):

Snap (creator) hi

However the print("changed creator") never is executed. Why is this?

edit: This is how I got channelRef?:

```
super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
if let channel = sender as? Channel {
    let chatVc = segue.destination as! channelMultiplayerViewController
    chatVc.channel = channel
    chatVc.channelRef = channelRef.child(channel.id)
    chatVc.usersKey = userKey

}
```

Printing more data:

```
        print("path channel ref: " + "\(self.channelRef)")
        print("snapshot: " + "\(snapshot)")
        print("value: " + "\(value)")
```

-path channel ref: Optional(https://X.com/channels/-KeGKaJavH6uPYaSa7k4)

-snapshot: Snap (creator) new Creator

-value: nil

**Update:**

data structure:

[image: structure]

*This will work for now, but isn't there a better approach?*:

```
        if snapshot.key == "creator"
        {
            changedCreator = snapshot.value as! String
        }
```

Another problem, exactly the same as above but with the solution for the first problem, this problem won't get solved. When I try to get the first child node, so the first user, and trying to get their userID, nothing works. I use this code:

```
let firstChild = UInt(1)
                    self.channelRef?.queryLimited(toFirst: firstChild).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                        print(snapshot)
                        print(value)
                        let newCreator = value?.value(forKey: "userID") as? String

                        if newCreator != nil{
                            print("Got the userID")
                        }
                        if snapshot.key == "userID"
                        {
                            print("Got the userID")
                        }
                    })
Snap (-KeJWMiXaL-FGp0J7b3u) {
    "-KeJWO0V9kxgGnrACAtP" =     {
        PictureVersion = 2;
        readyToGo = 0;
        userID = SZlQ76RLCJQpFa0CDhrgFJoYzrs2;
        username = pietje;
    };
}
Optional({
    "-KeJWO0V9kxgGnrACAtP" =     {
        PictureVersion = 2;
        readyToGo = 0;
        userID = SZlQ76RLCJQpFa0CDhrgFJoYzrs2;
        username = pietje;
    };
})
```

And this prints out, so no userID is given. Why is this? The userID is right there! I read the docs but it should work...

Comment: Can you include the line where you set the `channelRef?` variable?

Comment: It's possible you gave it a path that goes one level too deep into your database structure, like `"some_collection/an_object/readyToGo"` instead of `"some_collection/an_object"`, which would explain why `snapshot` is being returned as a string instead of a dictionary

Comment: I edited the question. Something is wrong when changing the data to the dictionary I think

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `chatVc.channelRef = channelRef.child(channel.id)` with `chatVc.channelRef = channelRef`

Comment: This way it will observe every single room in channels, it needs to be observing 1 channel. That channel is recognized by channel.id, so I think that part is working.

Comment: I know what you mean, but this way every person in every room is observing every room. I want it to be that every person in that room is just observing that only room. There is something wrong with having value's from that dictionary. When there is a map changed in that room channel (I have users in it that have a separated map), that value is not nil.

Comment: I know you included an example of the data structure at the end of your question, but can you also include what it looks like within the Firebase database? Because the path channels/channel-id needs to have at least one key/value pair in order to be casted to a dictionary

Comment: I updated the question. As you can see I have a few keys and a few values. But no matter what I try, it just won't take the value for key >:(